# Not able to convert payload to JSON after consuming message from Kafka Consumer in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-esb

I am using kafka consumer to consume the message from kafka. I am able to consume the messages when I tired to convert message to JSON or java using data weave. It is not getting transformed. Actually message kept is json. I could see type of message is string. could you please let me know how can we transform data

Answer (score 0):

Try using

**ByteArray to Object** Transformer

and then

**Object to JSON**   transformer

Alternatively you can also use "**Transform message**" with required input and output payload.

If you need specific transformation ,kindly specify the flow you are using.